# F3 Case sensitivity Mapper Error

Tags: sql-server, mapping, fat-free-framework

I am currently trying to use the mapper from Fat Free Framework with MS SQL Server :

```
    $reports = new DB\SQL\Mapper($f3->get('DB'),'Reports');
```

And I get the following error log :

PDOStatement: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'information_schema.columns'.

```
[C:/wamp32/www/lib/base.php:2032] Base->error(500,'PDOStatement: [Microsoft]
[ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'information_schema.columns'.')
[C:/wamp32/www/lib/db/sql.php:339] DB\SQL->exec('SELECT c.column_name AS field,c.data_type AS type,c.column_default AS defval,c.is_nullable AS nullable,t.constraint_type AS pkey FROM information_schema.columns AS c LEFT OUTER JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS k ON c.table_name=k.table_name AND c.column_name=k.column_name AND c.table_schema=k.table_schema AND c.table_catalog=k.table_catalog LEFT OUTER JOIN information_schema.table_constraints AS t ON k.table_name=t.table_name AND k.constraint_name=t.constraint_name AND k.table_schema=t.table_schema AND k.table_catalog=t.table_catalog WHERE c.table_name='Reports';',NULL,60)
```

It extracted the SELECT query and tried to run it directly on the Server and realized it was a case sensitivity issue, as it works fine when I run it uppercased.

My issue is that I can't find how to bypass this or to force the uppercased query. The documentation [here](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/sql-mapper) doesn't mention anything like this.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Please report that issue on the framework bug tracker: https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution in the lib/db/sql.php file.

You add the following to the $cmd array of supported engines, in the schema function :

```
'sqlsrv'=>array('SELECT '.
                    'C.COLUMN_NAME AS FIELD,'.
                    'C.DATA_TYPE AS TYPE,'.
                    'C.COLUMN_DEFAULT AS DEFVAL,'.
                    'C.IS_NULLABLE AS NULLABLE,'.
                    'T.CONSTRAINT_TYPE AS PKEY '.
                'FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C '.
                'LEFT OUTER JOIN '.
                    'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS K '.
                    'ON '.
                        'C.TABLE_NAME=K.TABLE_NAME AND '.
                        'C.COLUMN_NAME=K.COLUMN_NAME AND '.
                        'C.TABLE_SCHEMA=K.TABLE_SCHEMA '.
                        ($this->dbname?
                            ('AND C.TABLE_CATALOG=K.TABLE_CATALOG '):'').
                'LEFT OUTER JOIN '.
                    'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS T ON '.
                        'K.TABLE_NAME=T.TABLE_NAME AND '.
                        'K.CONSTRAINT_NAME=T.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND '.
                        'K.TABLE_SCHEMA=T.TABLE_SCHEMA '.
                        ($this->dbname?
                            ('AND K.TABLE_CATALOG=T.TABLE_CATALOG '):'').
                'WHERE '.
                    'C.TABLE_NAME='.$this->quote($table).
                    ($this->dbname?
                        (' AND C.TABLE_CATALOG='.
                            $this->quote($this->dbname)):'').
                ';',
                'FIELD','TYPE','DEFVAL','NULLABLE','YES','PKEY','PRIMARY KEY'),
```

Hope it will help.